# How can I keep jquery-1.5.2 and jquery-1.10.1.min from conflicting?

Tags: jquery

Hey I have my code that is all set up but there seems to be a conflict with jquery-1.5.2 and jquery-1.10.1.min how can I keep them from conflicting?

Comment: 1. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ 2. What if you rewrite it and stop using ancient versions?

Comment: If you can't rewrite the deprecated code, use the jQuery Migrate Plugin https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.5.2 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.betterTooltip.js">
</script>


    <!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_5_2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
//do stuff here like calling above two plugin 
//which support older versions
    </script>

    <!-- load jQuery 1.10.1 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

    <!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_10_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
//do stuff which support newer versions
    </script>
```

Then, instead of `$('#selector').function();`
 you'd do `jQuery_1_5_2 ('#selector').function();` 
for code working on 1.5.2
and `jQuery_1_10_1 ('#selector').function();.`
for code work on 1.10.1

but use them in lower to heigher version
i.e first use all the functions of 1.5.2 then use all 1.10.1